# Need to join 2 bodies via weld joint but not on center of mass

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, body

I have successfully join 2 bodies via weld joint , but my problem is I want to join corners of bodies not on centre of mass. Is there any way to achieve this?
[image]

Above image consist 3 polygon body that I want to join via weld joint. feel free to ask more information.
Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: You can specify an anchor point on both bodies in world space. This anchor point will be the position that both bodies are joined.